# Best way to kill a task using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to use "Taskkill" in Python to kill tasks, but running into several roadblocks. I was wondering if I'm going about this the right way or if there is a better way? Right now the code is not working at all, and just a black dos box appears briefly and goes away. I need to be able to program variables into the task kill, such as i need to be able to use it on my network over a distance. Basically it needs a username (for elevated privileges), The IP Address of the computer I'm connecting to, and the Task that needs the killing. The user name will need a password manually entered.

This is the part of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from socket import *
from subprocess import call

import platform
import os
import sys
import getpass

    def kill():
        ipad = ipaddress.get()
        tsk = tskille.get()
        os.system(['taskkill', '/u', 'domain\A'+usrnme, '/s '+ipad, '/F ', '/IM ' +tsk]) # Admin accounts are represeted by an "A" in front of the acctral username.
        return

usrnme = getpass.getuser()
tskille = StringVar() # label that can be overwritten manually to whatever
tskille.set("notepad.exe") # Just to put something in the box
ipaddress = StringVar() # have other code to determine the ip address of a pc.
ipaddress.set("0.0.0.0")
```

Initially i tried using "call" or "runCmd" and finally "os.system" but I'm definitely doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just curious, have you looked at powershell?  This exactly the type of stuff powershell is used for..  you could always use Python subprocess to call a powershell script. Assuming there aren't any bindings for powershell, which I almost expect there are.

Comment: I never actually never used powershell before, I was just used to old school DOS, but i think it would be about the same issues in python? have to figure out how to add the variables to the command?

Comment: What I mean is it's probably a one liner built into powershell to kill a task across the internet. I would bet you any money it's a core commandlet. Powershell enables you to add variables to the command as well. I think you could google this and be done in a few minutes.

Comment: If you run the command from a cmd prompt, what is your output? Alternatively, append an os.system("pause") to see what the output is.

Comment: I tried with the os.system - and i error out acctually - the "call" would open the dos box briefly. If i were to run this directly from dos i would use:

runas /user:domain\t%username% "taskkill /s %ipaddress% /F /IM notepad.exe"

Comment: I've also set variables in a batch file to do this, The goal for all this is i wanted a tool my admins can use aside from a funtioning batch file that already does all this. a "prettier" batch file so to speak, with buttons and do dads... We are limited in what software we can use here as well, otherwise i would have programmed it in C, but we have Python... and was just seeing if i could get something going. We also have an HTA program that does something similar... but this is more of a learning experience then anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[powershell tutorial](https://4sysops.com/archives/query-and-kill-a-process-on-a-remote-computer-using-powershell-and-wmi/)

To terminate a process using PowerShell, you can either use the WMI interface or use the Stop-Process cmdlet, which comes by default with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out it doesn't like the username part - it will not prompt for a password.. but this part works as intended:

```
def kill():
    usrnme = getpass.getuser()
    ipad = ipaddress.get()
    tsk = tskille.get()
    os.system("taskkill.exe /s %s /F /IM %s" % (ipad, tsk))
    return
```

the getpass.getuser() works as well, basically i just wanted it to be dynamic so that if others use it; it will scan their username and add:

```
os.system("taskkill.exe /u:domain\A%s /s %s /F /IM %s" % (usrnme, ipad, tsk))
```

But this code does not work causes the dos window to open and close immediately.